# In JFreeChart XYPlot how to change the bar colors

Tags: jfreechart

In JFreeChart `XYPlot`, how to change the bar colors?

Answer (score 2):

Use one of your chosen renderer's [`setSeriesPaint()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/AbstractRenderer.html#setSeriesPaint(int,%20java.awt.Paint%29) methods, as shown in this [example](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/demo/BarChartDemo1.html) and [code](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/demo/BarChartDemo1.html#line.64).